# Parametric equation of path on ellipsoid

Tags: parametric, parametrization

I am having trouble finding a parametric equation for the path $K$, with starting-point $(1,-1,0)$ and end-point $(-1,1,0)$, which is determined by the equations 
$$\begin{cases} 2x^2 + 2y^2 +z^2 = 4 \\ x + y + z =0 \\ z \geq 0
\end{cases}$$

I know the standard parametric equation for an ellipsoid but I seem to be stuck. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously we need only 1 parameter to describe a line whether curved or straight. Then adding up any extra parameter causes dependence between them. First take parameters $\phi,\theta$ such that:
$$x=\sqrt 2 sin(\theta)cos(\phi)$$
$$y=\sqrt 2 sin(\theta)sin(\phi)$$
$$z=2cos(\theta)$$
This satisfies first equation with one more parameter. To discover the dependence, substitute the above representations in the 2nd equation:
$$x+y+z=0\to sin(\theta)cos(\phi)+sin(\theta)sin(\phi)+\sqrt 2 cos(\theta)=0$$
which yields to
$$-cot\theta=sin(\phi+{\pi\over 4})$$
Now note the following:

$$x+y=2sin\theta sin(\phi+{\pi\over 4})$$

$$x+y=2sin\theta cos(\phi+{\pi\over 4})$$

Throughout the path from $startpoint$ to $endpoint$ we have $-{\pi\over 4}\le\phi\le{3\pi\over 4}$ therefore $0\le\phi+{\pi\over 4}\le \pi$ and then $cos(\phi+{\pi\over 4})\ge 0$ which leads to:

$$cos(\phi+{\pi\over 4})=\sqrt {1-cot^2(\theta)}$$
 This enables us to get to the parametric description:

$$x+y=-2cos\theta$$

$$x-y=2\sqrt {1-2cos^2\theta}$$

$$z=2cos\theta$$

which finally gives us:

$$x=-cos\theta+\sqrt {1-2cos^2\theta}$$

$$y=-cos\theta-\sqrt {1-2cos^2\theta}$$

$$z=2cos\theta$$

$${\pi\over 4} \le \theta \le {\pi\over 2}$$

There is an alternative way to represent this description:

$$x=-t+\sqrt {1-2t^2}$$

$$y=-t-\sqrt {1-2t^2}$$

$$z=2t$$

$$0 \le t \le \sqrt 2$$

Comment: Wow great! Thanks for your effort. I came as far as rewriting it to the parametric equation for the elipsoid, but I would have never thought of the following steps. Many thanks!

Comment: Don't mention it at all!!....... That's very kind of you!!!!

Comment: Please forward-slash your sins and coses -- it's pleasanter that way.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\eqalign{
  & \left\{ \matrix{
  2x^{\,2}  + 2y^{\,2}  + z^{\,2}  = 4 \hfill \cr 
  x + y + z = 0 \hfill \cr 
  0 \le z \hfill \cr}  \right.  \cr 
  & \left\{ \matrix{
  0 \le z =  - x - y \hfill \cr 
  3x^{\,2}  + 3y^{\,2}  + 2xy = 2\left( {x^{\,2}  + y^{\,2}  + 2xy} \right) + \left( {x^{\,2}  + y^{\,2}  - 2xy} \right) = 4 \hfill \cr}  \right.  \cr 
  & \left\{ \matrix{
  0 \le z =  - \left( {x + y} \right) \hfill \cr 
  {{\left( {x + y} \right)^{\,2} } \over {\left( {\sqrt 2 } \right)^{\,2} }} + {{\left( {x - y} \right)^{\,2} } \over {2^{\,2} }} = 1 \hfill \cr}  \right.  \cr 
  & \left\{ \matrix{
  x + y =  - z =  - \sqrt 2 \cos \theta  \hfill \cr 
  x - y = 2\sin \theta  \hfill \cr 
   - \pi /2 \le \theta  \le \pi /2 \hfill \cr}  \right. \cr} 
$$